# Tank Auth: Unable to select the specified database : xxxx

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

I am trying to use Tank Auth. I successfully created the tank tables in my database but when I load the page, it gives me this error:

```
Unable to select the specified database : testdb
```

I tried to google the solution but seems like it is the WAMP problem. But I just want to double check here to see if anyone solved this already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does indeed look like a problem with your dev environment. Are you sure you have configured the database correctly?

Try connecting to the database with the settings defined in `config/database.php` with a tool like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)